# Is it possible to have multiple mainloop for tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Basically I have built my app so that it creates two tkinter windows using multithreading. So I have two thread, each with it's tkinter class implemented. I now know that it was a terrible choice, but I didn't got much time and didn't study this solution before implementing it.

When I started a thread at a time all was good, except for a warning about mainloop not being in the main since I declared it in the thread that showed up just upon closing the window. I solved this problem starting the mainloop in the main through a function I built to get the window from the thread.

The problem now is, when I start both thread with both mainloop in the main through the two getwindow function I got an error about mainloop not being in the main and some images not found and the program doesn't start at all.

As now I learned a bit more about tkinter I now all the architecture was wrong to begin with. But there's a way to come around this problem without starting over again?

I tried to start the mainloop in each thread or starting them both in the main but neither works.

I just wanted two different windows that showed up two different function of my app

The way I built the system I got 2 thread like this:

```
class tkinterApp(tk.Tk):
...

class myThread(threading.Thread):
def __init__(self, threadID, name, counter):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    self.window = tkinterApp()
    self.threadID = threadID
    self.name = name
    self.counter = counter


def run(self):

    self.window.resizable(False, False)
    self.window.geometry("1000x600")
    self.window.config(background="white")
```

the tkinterApp class is totally different for the two threads. One is in a file named client and one in a file named importer_client. In the main I make them start like this:

```
threads = []

if 1:

    thread1_2 = importer_graphic.myThread(1, "importer_graphic", 1)

    thread1_2.start()
    threads.append(thread1_2)

    # thread_2 = client.myThread(2, "client", 2)
    # thread_2.start()
    # threads.append(thread_2)

    thread1_2.get_window().mainloop()
    # thread_2.get_window().mainloop()
for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

If i remove the comment line the program basically crash.

Comment: It's not clear why (you think) you need two main loops. Please provide a *minimal* example of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Why you don’t solve a second window as a Toplevel widget?

Comment: Can I easily turn my class into one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to have multiple mainloop for tkinter?

In short, no. You can have multiple calls to `mainloop()` but only one is active at a time. If you call `mainloop()` after one is already running, the running one is suspended until the new one exits.

> I just wanted two different windows that showed up two different function of my app

You don't need one `mainloop` per window. You can open as many windows as you want with a single call to `mainloop`. The first one should be an instance of `Tk`, and the second and subsequent windows should be instances of `Toplevel`.

Comment: It seems thatit was that easy.. thx <3 at least for now it's working ahah